# this code is desing for login page and when i click login button and want to show my main page . then login button not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login (LoginViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        DataBaseContext db = new DataBaseContext();
        var user = db.tblUsers.SingleOrDefault(x => x.UserName == model.UserName && x.Password == model.Password);
        if (user != null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Registration", "Home");

        }
        else
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid userName or Password");
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

this is for login Page code and when I run this code and move Registration page this does not work.

Comment: **this does not work** is very broad. Can you be more specific what does not work and what is your expected behavior ?

Comment: Hi . Shyju. my login page not work . i want to redirect my registration page

Comment: this code is for login page . please correct this .

Comment: i still don't understand what is not working. Can you be more specific about your problem. Edit the question with relevant details so that someone who has never looked at your code before can understand the problem.

Comment: Shyju .. Now understand my Question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "CotrollerName", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <label for="UserName">User Name:</label>
     @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserName)
     <label for="Password">User Name:</label>
     @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Password)
     <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 }
```

your view should look like this.